# What counts as a ground move?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

When a card boosts damage while on the ground, does this include moves that hover just above the ground such as Ryu's Tatsumaki? Does my feet have to be in contact with the ground to gain the bonus?

Comment: I personally would believe that card effects using that terminology would only include moves executed on the ground and thus moves that launch you into the air would not count but since I can't confirm this, I haven't posted an answer. In the case of tatsumaki, I believe that even though Ryu hovers above the ground, as the move does not change him into a jumping/falling state, etc. that this would still be considered "on the ground".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ground move is any move that is initiated while standing on the ground (as opposed to an aerial- or air- move, which is initiated, you guessed it, in the air).

Comment: so when I perform a dragon uppercut, even though it takes me into the air it will still receive the damage bonus?

Comment: By the above definition, yes.

Comment: @skovacs I know by what he said yes, but I want to make sure (i.e. have tested this in game or have a source)

Comment: Having not played with that particular card, I cannot 100% confirm this. Capcom are generally good at using the same terminology as the scene uses, in which case yes, the Shoryuken would count as a ground move.